# Update image using Radio button in Database in ASP using visual studio Debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

here is my code right now:

```
  //string sParameter = Request.QueryString["cn"];
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EKConn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd1;
    con.Open();
    //string scontenttype = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
    string sParameter = Request.QueryString["cn"];
    string sql;
    DateTime sDateTime;
    //sParameter = Request.QueryString["cn"];
    sDateTime = DateTime.Today;
    //  cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM tblCardRequestDetail2 where mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'", con);
    cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM tblphotoupload where mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader alinan_veri3;
    alinan_veri3 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
    //  int sCt;
    //  if (alinan_veri3.Read())
    //  {
    //      //sql = "update tblCardRequestDetail2 
            //       set mem_photo = @image, 
            //           mem_contenttype = '" + scontenttype + "' 
            //       where mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";
            //sql = "update tblCardRequestDetail2 
            //       set mem_photo = @image, 
            //           mem_contenttype = '" + scontenttype + "' 
            //       where mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";

    //      con.Close();
    //      SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EKConn"].ConnectionString);
    //      connection2.Open();

    //      SqlCommand cmd2 = null;
    //      cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection2);
    //      cmd2.Parameters.Add(UploadedImage);
    //      cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //      connection2.Close();
    //      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('Image saved!')", true);

    //      Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?cn=" + sParameter);
    // // }

    if (rbPhoto1.Checked == true)
    {

       sql = "update tblCardRequestDetail2 
              set tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_photo = tblphotoupload.mem_photo1,
                  tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_contenttype = tblphotoupload.mem_contenttype1 
              FROM tblCardRequestDetail2 
              INNER JOIN tblphotoupload 
              ON tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = tblphotoupload.mem_cardno  
              where tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";
        //sql = "update tblCardRequestDetail2 
        //       set mem_photo = @image, 
        //           mem_contenttype = '" + scontenttype + "' 
        //       where mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";

    }
    if (rbPhoto2.Checked == true)
    {
        sql = "update tblCardRequestDetail2 
               set tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_photo = tblphotoupload.mem_photo2,
                   tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_contenttype = tblphotoupload.mem_contenttype2 
               FROM tblCardRequestDetail2 
               INNER JOIN tblphotoupload 
               ON tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = tblphotoupload.mem_cardno  
               where tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";
    }
    if (rbPhoto3.Checked == true)
    {
        sql = "update tblCardRequestDetail2 
               set tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_photo = tblphotoupload.mem_photo3,
                   tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_contenttype = tblphotoupload.mem_contenttype3 
                FROM tblCardRequestDetail2 
                INNER JOIN tblphotoupload 
                ON tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = tblphotoupload.mem_cardno  
                where tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";
    }
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('Succesfully Uploaded your Image!')", true);

  //  Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?cn=" + sParameter);

}
```

and this is for the radio button:

```
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rbPhoto1" runat="server" Checked="True" Text="Photo 1" 
            oncheckedchanged="rbPhoto1_CheckedChanged" GroupName="RadioButton" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

whenever i click my update button and choose from the radio buttons .. it doesnt  update in the database..
 what i want to see is when i choose from the radio buttons it will update the content of mem_photo and mem_contenttype

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify your update sql statement first before integrating to your asp.

So far from my sql knowledge this update statement is bit off:

```
sql = "update tblCardRequestDetail2 
       set tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_photo = tblphotoupload.mem_photo3,
       tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_contenttype = tblphotoupload.mem_contenttype3 
       FROM tblCardRequestDetail2 
       INNER JOIN tblphotoupload 
       ON tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = tblphotoupload.mem_cardno  
       where tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";
```

I do assume your trying to related 2 tables but one must be a sub-query.

```
update tblCardRequestDetail2 
set tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_photo = tblphotoupload.mem_photo3,
    tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_contenttype = 
          (select tblphotoupload.mem_contenttype3 
           FROM tblCardRequestDetail2 
           INNER JOIN tblphotoupload 
           ON tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = tblphotoupload.mem_cardno)  
where tblCardRequestDetail2.mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";
```